# When exactly Patent No. US 7,716,161 B2 expire?

Tags: patent-lifetime, expiration

Can someone tell me when exactly [Patent No. US 7,716,161 B2](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US7716161.pdf) expire?

It's File on Dec. 6, 2002

Answer (score 1):

You should use the resources at the USPTO to determine this yourself. The USPTO maintains a [patent term calculator](https://www.uspto.gov/patent/laws-and-regulations/patent-term-calculator) that is helpful.

Comment: I have tried that calculator before posting this question. I was having problems with that calculator on my mac and couldn't figure it out.  Thats why I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7716161B2/en?oq=7%2C716%2C161), the expected expiration date is December 7, 2023. This is 366 days later than the filing date plus 20 years due to a patent term extension. I'm not qualified to give a legal opinion so don't take this as one.

Comment: The date of a provisional filing is not taken into consideration in determining the start of the term. The term ending date is calculated from the filing date not the effective date. From a Q & A on The Lens "What is the difference between effective filing date and priority date?
The filing date is the date when a patent application is first filed at a patent office. The priority date, sometimes called the "effective filing date", is the date used to establish the novelty and/or obviousness of a particular invention relative to other art"

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Thanks for clarifying that.